# Meteor: Connect to Collection dynamically based on user input

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm new to Meteor and Mongo so there's a good chance that this is an easy solve, but I've been racking my brains for days and can't figure out a way to do it.

Basically, I have a collection that contains a bunch of documents that render to a web page as a list. When I user chooses an item, that item corresponds to a collection whose name matches the ID of the item. So once selected, I want to retrieve the contents of the collection that is referenced by that document.

In effect I want to be able to dynamically update:

```
dynamicCollection = new Mongo.Collection(selectedItemId);
```

Where `selectedItemId` is a dynamically updated variable based on a user selection.

I've tried using global and window references but just keep getting errors when calling find().

Comment: `Mongo.Collection` constructor expects collection name, not some "variable based on user input". I think you want something like `collection.find(...)`.

Comment: @Styx The variable would be the name of a collection that hadn't previously been set up using `new Mongo.Collection()`

Comment: Ah, I got it. Show examples of `selectedItemId` values, please.

Comment: selectedItemId is populated when a user selects an item in a list. The _id of that item then becomes the selectedItemId. It's a string. This _id is also the name of a collection. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Why don't you want to use something like `Meteor.call('getItemsFrom', selectedItemId, (e, items) => { ... });`?

Comment: I've kind of been trying to do that. Assuming that I pass in the correct collection name. Should this work?  ` 'mylog.find' (selectedItemId) {const collection = new Mongo.Collection(selectedItemId);return collection.find({}).fetch`

Comment: You won't know until you try :) Yes, something like that should work, just don't forget that `.fetch()` is a method.